# How do I iterate through these arguments to filter an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, callback, arguments

So I have this code, which does what it needs to do, which is return an input array minus any values that match the arguments after the array. But, I am having trouble figuring out how to iterate through all the arguments. Here is what I have working -

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  var arg2 = arguments[1];
  var arg3 = arguments[2];
  var arg4 = arguments[3];
  var result = arr.filter(function(arg) {
    if (arg != arg2 && arg != arg3 && arg != arg4) {
      return (arg);
    }
  });
  return result;
}
destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

And here is my attempt at iterating through all arguments with a for loop. It is not working and I am struggling to conceptualize what exactly I am pumping through my callback in the arr.filter here -

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  var result = arr.filter(function(arg) {
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      if (arg != arguments[i]) {
        return (arg);
      }
    }
  });
  return result;
}
destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Is this close to where I need to be or am I way off here?

Answer (score 1):

The `arguments` variable is set on each function call, including the call to your `.filter()` callback. Thus `arguments` in that callback is not what you think it is.

You can do what you're trying to do with `.indexOf`, and you'll need to copy they arguments into another array:

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  var badValues = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; ++i)
    badValues = arguments[i];
  return arr.filter(function(value) {
    return badValues.indexOf(value) < 0;
  });
}
```

It's popular to use `.slice()` to copy all or part of the `arguments` object:

```
  var badValues = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
```

You can do that if you like the brevity, but passing the `arguments` object out of a function makes it very hard to optimize.

Comment: Thanks I got a version of this to work. Notable changes were pushing the arguments to badValues and setting the filter function to test for indexes === -1.

Comment: @slurrr yes sorry I got the test backwards :) Glad you worked it out!